# How to pass additional data to Castle interceptor?

Tags: c#, wcf, rabbitmq, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a class that is exposed as a WCF service. The class lifetime is managed by Castle Windsor, which attaches a number of interceptors like logging aspect and permission aspect. With WCF I can pass some additional data in message headers, like the username or a userSessionId. Then on the server side the Permission interceptor can use **OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders** and read which user is making the call. Then it can allow the invocation to proceed or throw an exception.

The problem is that now I want to ditch WCF and replace it with something else (RabbitMQ to be excact). How can I get a similar functionality to WCF OperationContext.Current, but without WCF? Or otherwise add some additional data to an IInvocation, so the interceptor would be able to read? The interceptor must be transparent to the rest of the world as usual.

Comment: What about maybe changing the binding to be one that works with RabbitMQ instead of not using WCF?

Comment: I thought about that. But on the RabbitMQ website it reads: The .NET/C# RabbitMQ client library should be used in preference to the WCF binding where possible. The WCF binding suffers from a number of limitations and no further development is planned for it. The limitations are described in the WCF Service Model documentation.

Comment: "Any software problem can be fixed by adding another layer"  , what if you add an extra layer and retrieve extra parameter  from invocation arguments? Does it make sense?

Comment: That is exactly what MS did with WCF, so I didn't have to implement it myself. Of course I can implement a layer that will do it. My question was about whether there is some built-in functionality within RabbitMQ, that can do it.